# Add navigation to component onPress (React-Navigation)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

In my app I have a FlatList component which renders the component below (effectively a row with small snippets of information), I'd like to have it so that I can click on each component within the FlatList which then takes the user to another screen which provides more details.

I've managed to make it so that each component is clickable and I can make it perform an alert() to show that it is clickable, but using React-Navigation is proving a tad tricky for me to add.

FlatList page:

```
/* @flow*/

import _ from 'lodash'
import {getAllQuestions} from './questionRepository'
import ProfilePicture from './components/ProfilePicture'
import QuestionerAndQuestion from './questionRow/QuestionerAndQuestion'
import Separator from './components/Separator'
import {Button, FlatList} from 'react-native'
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class QuestionList extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'AIBU',
        headerRight: (
            <Button
                onPress={_.debounce(() => {
                    navigation.navigate('Add')
                }, 500)}
                title="Add"
            />
        ),
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(245, 245, 245)',
        },
        headerLeft: <ProfilePicture size={'small'} />,
    })

    state = {questions: []}

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData()
    }

    async getData() {
        const questions = await getAllQuestions()

        this.setState({questions})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
                ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
                data={this.state.questions}
                renderItem={({item}) => <QuestionerAndQuestion item={item} />}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

QuestionerAndQuestion component:

```
/* @flow */

import ProfilePicture from '../components/ProfilePicture'
import React from 'react'
import TextContainer from './TextContainer'
import {StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View} from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    row: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
        height: 125,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    profilePic: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    textBody: {
        flex: 6,
    },
})

const QuestionerAndQuestion = ({item}: {item: Object}) =>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigate would go here?}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
            <View style={styles.profilePic}>
                <ProfilePicture />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.textBody}>
                <TextContainer item={item} />
            </View>
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

export default QuestionerAndQuestion
```

Comment: What do you mean by "alert all the information"? I'm assuming you want to do something and then navigate? It's a bit hard to tell what the error you're running into is.

Comment: @MichaelCheng sorry to clarify, I can make it do an alert() to show that the row is clickable (edited question now) - but I'm not sure how to navigate from this screen to another, I've managed to add navigation to a screen like you can see in the QuestionList class, but not sure how to add it into the QuestionerAndQuestion component

Answer (score 0):

I assume you navigated to the `QuestionList` component, therefore, you have the `navigation` object on there. What you would want to do is pass the `navigation` down to the `QuestionerAndQuestion` as a prop and then you can access it from `onPress` as a prop.

Something like this:

`<QuestionerAndQuestion item={item} navigation={this.props.navigation} />`

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you write an example how to send a prop to `QuestionerAndQuestion` from his `QuestionList`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, an undefined object appears to be passed

Comment: Managed to get it to work. - The component QuestionerAndQuestion is for presentation, whereas the QuestionList is the screen and controls the navigation. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.

Within `QuestionList`

```
render() {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation

    return (
        <FlatList
            ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
            data={this.state.questions}
            renderItem={({item}) =>
                <QuestionerAndQuestion item={item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Question')} />}
        />
    )
}
```

Within `QuestionerAndQuestion`

```
const QuestionerAndQuestion = ({item, onPress}: {item: Object, onPress: Object}) =>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
```